# How to find all unique possible ways of partition from specific data given of an integer

Tags: java

I want to make java program that count all unique possible ways from specific data (array list) given of an integer.

```html
Example :
input: 3 6
       1 2 3 
output: 7

explanation: the first line contains two separated integers of value x,y.
the second line contains x separated integers

For y = 6 and x = {1, 2, 3} there are exactly seven ways:       
1. {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} <— sum up to 6       
2. {1, 1, 1, 1, 2} <- sum up to 6
3. {1, 1, 1, 3} <- sum up to 4
4. {2, 2, 2} <— sum up to 6
5. {2, 2, 1, 1} <— sum up to 6
6. {1, 2, 3} <— sum up to 6
7. {3, 3} <- sum up to 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For a given integer a, find all unique combinations of positive integers that sum up to a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046561/for-a-given-integer-a-find-all-unique-combinations-of-positive-integers-that-su)

Comment: Not same as my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I think what you're asking is "count the number of ways to add up to `y` using only a set of numbers as possible summands".

I assume that the numbers in the second line are all distinct, are all less than `y` (well, this is not really necessary), and are positive.

One solution is to use a recursive approach. Say `f(y, {x_1, ..., x_n})` is the number of ways to add up to `y` using only `x_i`'s.

Then `f(y, {x_1, ..., x_n}) = sum of f(y - x_i, {x_1, ..., x_n}) for i = 1, ..., n`.

You can write a recursive function now. What's the base case? Well, `y` could be 0, so the answer would be 1. Or `y` could be negative, and the answer would be 0.

That should do it. But it will probably be very inefficient. I encourage you to read up on recursion and calculating Fibonacci numbers to learn how you can be more efficient (hint: memoization, and a bottoms-up approach instead of a top-down approach are your friends).